# Firebase auth database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am working on the app that I need to connect to the dev firebase.
This firebase has database rules as follows:

```
"rules": {
    // no read access at root level
    ".read": "auth.uid === 'emailaddressgmailcom'",
    ".write": false,
```

What I cannot understand is how `auth.uid` is specified to be an exact email address?
As far as I tried I only get unique uid provided by Google. (set of numbers and letters)
Hence I can never pass the auth to read from the database, unless I specify my exact `uid` given by Google in the databse rules, which is not an option because there will be another user who needs an access to db and I do not know his `uid`.

Answer (score 0):

[`auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#auth) is one of the [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables).

By doing `auth.uid`, you get the user id ("guaranteed to be unique across all providers").

You need, in your Security Rules to use it to defined the access rights of a given user to one or more given resources, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) in the doc.

You could compare it to a fixed value, if a certain resource shall be read by a unique user:

```
".read": "auth.uid === 'HGH656675FHGFGHF3454'"
```

but usually you compare it to some parts of the path of the node/resource you want to protect, like for example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you should do to solve your problem "there will be another user who needs an access to db and I do not know his `uid`".

---

I would suggest you read the entire section about RTDB Security Rules form more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Answer (score 0):

Please try below rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token